# CSS transform that looks like a hardcover book being opened?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS transform on a div that makes it look like the cover of a book opening.

This means the left side is bound, and the right side flys towards the user getting larger.

Can anyone offer some direction? If it works in webkit that is all I need!

EDIT: I'm looking for the effect you would find with a hardcover book. I don't want the pages to bend or fold, just the right side comes out at the user.

I've done this, it's pretty close but I can't get the left side to lock in place.

```
@-webkit-keyframes BookCover
    0%
        -webkit-transform perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg)
        opacity 1
    100%
        -webkit-transform perspective(400px) rotateY(-90deg)
        opacity 0
```

got it, you need to change the orgin `-webkit-transform-origin top left`

Answer (score 2):

CSS Play has a demo for a css only flipbook : http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/peter-rabbit.html
Take a look at the source for some inspiration.

To create a more true 3D effect, the [matrix3D tranformations](http://9elements.com/html5demos/matrix3d/) are the coolest thing since sliced bread, but currently only supported in Chrome.

**EDIT:**
Created a a little test fiddle for 3D transforms, try tweaking it to get the result you want :

http://jsfiddle.net/XnA2f/

Comment: I don't want a page peel effect. I'm thinking hardcover, css transform  using perspective and rotate y is promising but I haven't figured it out. I only need it to work in webkit too.

Comment: Thanks very much, I already got it though using perspective, see below.

Answer (score 2):

here's a fiddle I just made for a peel effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/TW43V/17/

for a hardcover feel you would have to play around with rotate3d, which only works on the iOS and Safari mac OS X as far as I know.

peel effect with rotate3d (Safari OS X)

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/TW43V/18/

UPDATE:

### basic hardcover flip

[Hardcover CSS flip](http://codepen.io/pixelass/pen/qdwGD)

```
.book {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 2000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 45%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 100%);
}

.page {
  height: 270px;
  width: 285px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  transition: transform 300ms linear;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0, #fff 10%, #fff 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 100%);
  z-index: 1;

  &:hover {
    z-index: 2;
  }



  &.flipped {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/page-flip.html

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm more so looking for a hardcover flip, using perspective instead of page bending.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it before but I would imagine that CSS could only go so far. I think Jquery is maybe a bit of a better option.

But if I was to do it in CSS i'd have a container div that then uses the CSS pseudo selector :before or :after. Which simply attaches an element to another using only CSS. I'd style them however. Then I would expand using -webkit-transform or whatever, when the user hovers etc.

Heres a guy thats pretty good with CSS and design in general, he has a free example
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-page-peel-effect-with-jquery-css/

Heres a link to the pseudo selector

http://w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

Comment: I don't want a page peel effect. I'm thinking hardcover, thanks thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
@-webkit-keyframes BookCover
    0%
        -webkit-transform perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg)
        -webkit-transform-origin top left
    100%
        -webkit-transform perspective(400px) rotateY(-90deg)
        -webkit-transform-origin top left
```

(written in stylus)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>book cover</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

div:hover {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease; 
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) skewY(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fvA5/3/) for a live demo.